# XStream: Get elements without mapping parent element to a wrapper class

Tags: java, xstream

I'd like to deserialize the following (simplified) XML with XStream:

```
<order>
    <head>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
        <date>2015-05-21 12:34:56</date>
        <customer>John Doe</customer>
    </head>
    <positions>
        <position>
            <number></number>
            <text></text>
            <amount></amount>
        </position>
        <!-- more positions here -->
    </positions>
</order>
```

The resulting object has this layout:

```
public class Order {
    private int orderNumber;
    private int date;
    private String customer;

    private List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
}
```

I know how to place all the required annotations from XStream in these classes. But as you can already see, there is no class or attribute to account for the `<head>` element and thus deserialization fails with an `UnknownFieldException` for "head".

Can XStream map the children of `<head>` to `class Order` without providing a mapping for `<head>` itself?

Comment: I think the only way is to write your own converter, which is not too complicated.